# Model backing the '...' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, data-migration

I have enable-migration as well enablemigration=true. But i have table definition to save all form fields. Its keeps throwing this error. " System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The model backing the 'eNtsaRegistration' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)".  What i want to achieve is when i send all the fields from the form they must send it to my table definition. I can get the list of all countries when form is loaded and select them. What am i missing exactly?

```
        // Migration Folder. 
        using System;
        using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
        
        namespace eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Migrations
        {
            public partial class eNtsaRegistration : Migration
            {
                protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
                {
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "__MigrationHistory",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            MigrationId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 150, nullable: false),
                            ContextKey = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 300, nullable: false),
                            Model = table.Column<byte[]>(nullable: false),
                            ProductVersion = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 32, nullable: false)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory", x => new { x.MigrationId, x.ContextKey });
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "AspNetRoles",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            Id = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                            Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
                            DisplayName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "AspNetUsers",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            Id = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                            FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            LocalAddress = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            PermanentAddress = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                            EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                            PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                            TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                            LockoutEndDateUtc = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: true),
                            LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                            AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                            UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
                            ProfilePicPath = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "Dietary",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            None = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
                            Vegetarian = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                            Vegan = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                            Halaal = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                            Other = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: true)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Dietary", x => x.None);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "Locations",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            Latitute = table.Column<decimal>(type: "numeric(18, 0)", nullable: true),
                            Longitute = table.Column<decimal>(type: "numeric(18, 0)", nullable: true),
                            Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Locations", x => x.Name);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "TbTrainingForm",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                            Title = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            FirstName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            LastName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            Position = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            Company = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            StreetAddress = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                            StreetAddressLine = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                            City = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            StateProvince = table.Column<string>(name: "State/Province", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            ZipCode = table.Column<int>(name: "Zip/Code", nullable: false),
                            Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                            CellNumber = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                            DietaryRequirement = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                            UserId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                            ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                            ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                            table.ForeignKey(
                                name: "FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId",
                                column: x => x.UserId,
                                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                                principalColumn: "Id",
                                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                            ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                            UserId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey, x.UserId });
                            table.ForeignKey(
                                name: "FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId",
                                column: x => x.UserId,
                                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                                principalColumn: "Id",
                                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                        name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                        columns: table => new
                        {
                            UserId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                            RoleId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false)
                        },
                        constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                            table.ForeignKey(
                                name: "FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                                column: x => x.RoleId,
                                principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                                principalColumn: "Id",
                                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                            table.ForeignKey(
                                name: "FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId",
                                column: x => x.UserId,
                                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                                principalColumn: "Id",
                                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                        });
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                        name: "RoleNameIndex",
                        table: "AspNetRoles",
                        column: "Name",
                        unique: true);
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                        name: "IX_UserId",
                        table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                        column: "UserId");
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                        name: "IX_UserId",
                        table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                        column: "UserId");
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                        name: "IX_RoleId",
                        table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                        column: "RoleId");
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                        name: "IX_UserId",
                        table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                        column: "UserId");
        
                    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                        name: "UserNameIndex",
                        table: "AspNetUsers",
                        column: "UserName",
                        unique: true);
                }
        
                protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
                {
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "__MigrationHistory");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "AspNetUserClaims");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "AspNetUserLogins");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "AspNetUserRoles");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "Dietary");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "Locations");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "TbTrainingForm");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "AspNetRoles");
        
                    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                        name: "AspNetUsers");
                }
            }
        }
    
    // Controller
    public ActionResult SaveRegForm()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Details saved successfull";
                return View(db.TrainingRegs.ToList()); // Error is thrown here.
            }
    
       //GET:TrainingRegForm/Submit.
           public ActionResult SubmitRegDetails()
            {
                // Initialization.
                this.ViewBag.CountryList = this.GetCountryList();
                this.ViewBag.SaveRegForm = this.SaveRegForm();
    
                RegViewAndRoleViewModel model = new RegViewAndRoleViewModel();
    
                return View(model);
            }
    
    // Model
      public partial class TbTrainingForm
        {
            [Key]
            public Guid? Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Position { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            
            public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    
           
            public string StreetAddressLine { get; set; }
    
            
            public string City { get; set; }
    
            public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    
            
            public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    
            public string Country { get; set; }
    
           
            public string Email { get; set; }
    
            
            public int CellNumber { get; set; }
            public string DietaryRequirement { get; set; }
        }

using System.Data.Entity;
using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models;

namespace eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL
{
    public class eNtsaRegistration:DbContext
    {

        public eNtsaRegistration() : base("eNtsaRegistration")
        {
        }  public DbSet<TrainingRegForm> TrainingRegs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
 }

// View
@model eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models.RegViewAndRoleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRegForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {


                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            <hr />

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Title" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegForm.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegForm.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegForm.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Name" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegForm.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>

}
```

Comment: [Review] changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large part of your Entity Framework related .cs files are generated classes (**mapping views**) that should match your database and the table definitions.

When the mapping views do not match your latest changes in database or (modified, migrated) DbContext, you get this error message.

Did you install the EF power tools extension ? You can find it online in the Visual Studio Extensions menu.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition

..when you install it, there is a right-click to generate new mapping view files for your DbContext.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/pre-generated-views-with-a-code-first-model-entity-framework/

Comment: when installing EF power tool, i wont need any enable-migration etc? no will i get that error as indicated here from this topic?